# getdoubleValuer() devuelve 0.0 cuando el numero es negativo

Tags: double

tengo un datasnapshot de un nodo de firebase y sus datos estan todos bien asi como los necesito, el problema lo tengo cuando trato de tomar el mensajero.getLng_dir_ini() ya que me devuelve siempre 0.0 y su valor en cosola desde el datasnapshot.getValue().toString() se ve bien un double negativo

```
           //Inicializar la lista de mensjaeros conectados
        MensajerosConectados = new ArrayList<>();
        ListenerLocacionConectados = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                Mensajeros mensajero = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mensajeros.class);
                MensajerosConectados.add(mensajero);
                //aqui agregamos el marcador de cada mensajero
                if (mensajero!=null) {
                        LatLng poscision_mensajero = new LatLng(mensajero.getLat_dir_ini(),mensajero.getLng_dir_ini());
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(poscision_mensajero)
                                .title(mensajero.getNombre())
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.boton_carro)));
                }

// aqui la consola imprime para lat_dir_ini un valor entero pero lng_dir_ini // aparece como 0.0 y ese es mi error ya que no se porque en el datasnapshot si // se ve el numero pero en el objeto mensajero me trae 0.0
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue()!=null) {
                    Log.i("On Child Aded data "," "+mensajero.getLat_dir_ini()+ mensajero.getLng_dir_ini() );
```

//aqui me imprime en consola los valores bien, donde lng_dir_ini tiene un valor double negativo.
                        Log.i("On Child Aded data "," "+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString() );
                        try {
                            Log.i("LIsta Mensajeros","hay  "+MensajerosConectados.size());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

```
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Mensajeros mensajero = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mensajeros.class);

                if (mensajero!=null && MensajerosConectados.size()>0) {
                    for(int i = 0; i< MensajerosConectados.size();i++){
                        if(mensajero.getCodigo().equals(MensajerosConectados.get(i).getCodigo())){

                            Log.i("quitar Mensajeros","remover  "+MensajerosConectados.get(i).getNombre());
                            MensajerosConectados.remove(i);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        Query_conectados.addChildEventListener(ListenerLocacionConectados);

// clase mensajeros
public class Mensajeros {

    private String nombre;
    private float calificacion;
    private String placa;
    private String codigo;
    private String urlFoto;
    private String telefono;
    private String token;
    private double lat_dir_ini;
    private double lng_dir_ini;






    public  Mensajeros(){

    }

    public Mensajeros(String nombre,String urlFoto,float calificacion,
                      String codigo,String placa, String telefono,double lat_dir_ini,double lng_dir_ini, String token){

        Log.d("Clase Mensajeros","longitud "+lng_dir_ini);

        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.calificacion = calificacion;
        this.urlFoto = urlFoto;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.lat_dir_ini = lat_dir_ini;
        this.lng_dir_ini = lng_dir_ini;
        this.token = token;

    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }


    public float getCalificacion() {
        return calificacion;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setCalificacion(float calificacion) {
        this.calificacion = calificacion;
    }
    public String getUrlFoto() {
        return urlFoto;
    }

    public void setUrlFoto(String urlFoto) {
        this.urlFoto = urlFoto;
    }



    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public double getLat_dir_ini() {
        return lat_dir_ini;
    }

    public double getLng_dir_ini() {

    //*** aqui tengo el problema, en mi nodo esto es un double negativo pero aqui me imprime 0.0
        Log.d("Clase Mensajeros","longitud"+lng_dir_ini);
        return lng_dir_ini;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y los demás valores (double lat_dir_ini, etc.) también te imprimen 0.0 o null?

Comment: Esto parece `firebase` y `android` ¿por qué sólo pones la etiqueta `double` y ¿qué relevancia tiene realmente esa etiqueta?

Comment: ¿Qué imprime el Log que tienes al inicio de la clase: `Log.d("Clase Mensajeros","longitud "+lng_dir_ini);`?  no el de `getLng_dir_ini` ... si ahí te imprime también `0.00` entonces el problema es de los datos que traes de Firebase, deberías revisar el contenido de `dataSnapshot`

Comment: El datasnapshot emprime una longitud es decir, un valor double con signo negativo, y los demas datos por ejempolo el de el getlat_dir_ini() si devuelve un entero. supongo que algo tiene que ver el signo ya que el de la latitud esta en positivo y lo trae bien pero el de la longitud que está en negativo lo devuelve 0.0

Comment: acabo de hacer una prueba con la longitud con un numero positivo y la latitud uno negativo y el resultado es el mismo, getLat_dir_ini() me trae el numero negativo perfectamente pero getLng_dir_ini() sigue trayendo 0.0 entonces no es problema del signo

Answer (score 0):

Me dá vergüenza decirlo pero el problema era un error en los nombres de las variables, la cual estaba en firebase como lgn_dir_ini y en java como getLng_dir_ini() por eso siempre me devolvía el valor 0.0 agradezco a todos por su intención.